# Доступ к общей папке Windows из под Docker`а в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, virtualbox

Помогите решить проблему с правами доступа. Система выглядит так:

`Windows 10 Home > VirtualBox > Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 > Docker > nginx`.

С винды шарится папка Docker, которая в Ubuntu отображается как

`drwxrwx--- root vboxsf sf_Docker`

Nginx пытается получить доступ к sf_Docker от юзера/группы www-data, но доступ запрещен.
Видел много советов сделать `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data`, но результата никакого. Единственное что решает проблему это перемонтировать папку с пользователем/группой www-data (`sudo mount -t vboxsf Docker -o rw,gid=33,uid=33 /media/sf_Docker`), но такой вариант не совсем подходит.

Comment: `sf_Docker` - это папка?

Comment: @mix да, в винде она Docker, в ubuntu монтируется как sf_Docker